# How to run custom domain name in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, azure, azure-compute-emulator

I want to run my application through azure project in Visual Studio. But it runs it not as I expected. It runs the project like: `http://127.0.0.1:82/` not as I want: `http://testproject.com`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running the site on your local machine you can update your [Hosts File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) so that it includes an entry for testproject.com that points to 127.0.0.1 while you're testing.  When you're done testing make sure you remove the entry in this file.

Answer (score 1):

Once you push it to the cloud you can use a dns cname to redirect your domain. Here's an article that explains it more http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure

Comment: But I need to test my application with my domain in Visual Studio, I am changing routing with mvc.

Comment: @Sergey, unless you are routing by subdomain, your MVC routes should not care about the root domain your app is hosted on.